# Terminate the NSURLConnection ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am creating a `NSURL` connection for a `UIWebView` authentication. It's working fine, but I am not be able to be authorized for some reason. If I enter the wrong password, it won't let me try login again with the correct password. What is the best way to terminate the `NSURLconnection`?

I tried this :

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
  NSString *errorText = [[error userInfo] description];
  NSLog (@"----------------------------------------------");
  NSLog (@"STEP 4 - connection didFailWithError");
  NSLog (@"Error message: %@", errorText);
  connection = nil;
}
```

But it's not working for some reason.

Comment: Did you try making cancel API call before marking the connection nil ? See this http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: setting the pointer to nil has no effect here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to terminate NSURLConnection in the way you want to do it.

Implemented the following NSURLConnection delegate method to change credentials (login/pass):

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
```

In this method you have a change to provide a new credentials. Something like that:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    NSLog(@"received authentication challenge");
    NSURLCredential *newCredential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"USER"
                                                                password:@"PASSWORD"
                                                             persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
    NSLog(@"credential created");
    [[challenge sender] useCredential:newCredential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    NSLog(@"responded to authentication challenge");    
}
```